# Provisioning of SharePoint Site and Lists from the MS Teams Personal App

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I would like to provision a SharePoint Site and Lists from the Microsoft Teams Personal App.
I know that can be done if used as channel app.

But my requirement is to provision site/subsite from the Teams Personal app only.

I am ready to use Flow or PnP if I get the context.

I am stuck in this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create a personal static tab and upload that manifest to Teams. You can provide sharepoint address for contentUrl.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#statictabs 
`"staticTabs": [
  {
    "entityId": "spsite",
            "name": "sp site",
            "contentUrl": "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/RAExperts",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
  }  ]`

Comment: This siteurl is going to be dynamic, so cannot be put inside manifest. Like a Product

Comment: We will check internally and get back to you.

Comment: Engineering team has confirmed that this is currently not supported.